# concat value of multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql, teradata

SOURCE DATA:

```
COLA    COLB   COLC
1       BO     AFV
1       BO     AKG
1       BO     UYD
2       BOS    KJHSDKJ
2       BOS    YWI
3       POS    JHSFJH
3       POS    IUXN
```

My desired result is below:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC
1       BO      AFV, AKG,UYD
2       BOS     KJHSDKJ,YWI
3       POS     JHSFJH,IUXN
```

COLA, COLB are the key columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive query that will do the job:

```
WITH RECURSIVE REC_VIEW (COLA, COLB, ROLL_UP, COLC) 
AS
(
SELECT COLA
     , COLB
     , MIN(COLC) (VARCHAR(1000))
     , MIN(COLC)
FROM  your_table
GROUP BY 1,2
UNION ALL
SELECT B.COLA
     , B.COLB
     , B.ROLL_UP || ',' || A.COLC
     , A.COLC
FROM   your_table A 
INNER JOIN REC_VIEW B
ON    A.COLA = B.COLA
  AND A.COLB = B.COLB
  AND A.COLC > B.COLC
)

SELECT COLA, COLB, ROLL_UP as COLC
FROM REC_VIEW

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLA, COLB
                           ORDER BY CHARACTER_LENGTH(ROLL_UP) DESC) = 1
```

I wish I understood how to format answers better; all my "pretty" spacing has disappeared.  Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  Something is royally messed up with my copy of IE 8 (customized by our esteemed IT department); I just looked at this again with Chrome and I see it formatted properly.  Guess I'll start using Chrome more often!

Comment: You're welcome! I only use IE when I have to and that is typically Outlook Web Access only. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](http://thesimpleprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/02/concat-rows-as-single-column-in-teradata.html) to a sample.

It has some sample data and an actual query.